# Google Maps v3 - resize on parent container resize

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can resize on window change with :

```
//on window resize
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
     var center = map.getCenter();
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
     map.setCenter(center); 
});
```

, but how to resize when window does not change and only the width/height of the maps container does?  Here, the sidebar menu of my site can be opened/closed... when this happens the maps container changes width.

This does not seem to do anything and not sure why. Perhaps it is getting the map center after the change has already been made?

```
//on sidebar open/close
$('body').on('click', '.sidebar-toggler', function (e) {
     var center = map.getCenter();
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
     map.setCenter(center); 
});
```

**More info:**

If I use a timeout then this works as I expected it to.  Thing is I don't have any animation on my sidebar open/close so is it just a matter of needing the open/close to happen before the actual call is made?

```
//redraw if sidebar open/close
$('body').on('click', '.sidebar-toggler', function (e) {            
    setTimeout(function() {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: This should help you: http://wellcaffeinated.net/articles/2012/12/10/very-simple-css-only-proportional-resizing-of-elements/